# nicolaslopezj/searchable: How I can set configuration for multiple joins with single table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, searchable

Currently, I've the below table structure, The projects table has one General Contact(belongs to one user from users) and another one is technical user(many to many relation with users table). I have used the searchable package but it search for only general contacts / technical contacts not for both. How can set the configuration for both query?

> Projects
>   - id
>   - name
>   - general_contact(one user from users table)
>   - description
>
> Projects_has_tech_users
>   - projects_id
>   - users_id
>
> Users
>   - id
>   - firstname
>   - lastname
>   - email
>   - password
>   - role

Here is the searchable configuration which I've set in Project Model.

```
protected $searchable = [
    'columns' => [
        'projects.name' => 1,
        'users.first_name' => 2,
        'users.last_name' => 2,
        'projects.description' => 3,
    ],
    'joins' => [
        'projects_has_tech_users' => ['projects.id','projects_has_tech_users.projects_id'],
        'users' => ['projects_has_tech_users.users_id', 'users.id'],
        'users' => ['projects.general_contact', 'users.id']
    ],
    'groupBy'=>'projects.id'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution by giving the alias with the join table

```
protected $searchable = [
    'columns' => [
        'projects.name' => 1,
        'tech.first_name' => 3,
        'tech.last_name' => 3,
        'gen.first_name' => 3,
        'gen.last_name' => 3,
        'projects.description' => 4,
    ],
    'joins' => [
        'projects_has_tech_users' => ['projects.id','projects_has_tech_users.projects_id'],
        'users as tech' => ['projects_has_tech_users.users_id', 'tech.id'],
        'users as gen' => ['projects.general_contact', 'gen.id']
    ],
    'groupBy'=>'projects.id'
];
```